# I have a 2009 Chevy impala and when you put it in drive the car moved about 5 feet then when I push on the gas the engine revs like it’s in neutral

Tags: automatic-transmission

Do I need a new Engine? It has an automatic transmission do I need new transmission? Is it a valve or belt ? Please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Because the motor starts and runs, you don't need a new engine. ("Valve" or "belt" sound like engine parts. They're working fine, and don't need replacement.)

There is, however, a problem with the transmission. It may be low on transmission fluid, or need some other service. It may be beyond servicing and require replacement. Given your level of mechanical knowledge, I'd take the car to a transmission shop. If the car doesn't move under its own power, then you'll have to have it towed.

Comment: Thank you very much I do have a small transmission leak but I also added 4 art of transmission fluid but still not wanting to stay in drive mode if I  turn the car off and let it sit for about 15 seconds then turn it back on most of the time I’ll be able to drive about 5 to 10 feet but then it goes back into the neutral mode to where the engines revving when I push on the gas I appreciate your answer thank you